# How to estimate population statistics for each category?

Tags: estimation, sampling, experiment-design

I have data from a simple random sample having n elements which I’m using as an unbiased estimate for my population statistics (mean). My population can be divided into k categories, and I know the composition of my overall population in terms of these categories. As part of my study, I want to estimate the statistic for each category of my population. Unfortunately, I do not have a stratified random sample with me.

Question - Given what I have, is there any way to fairly (i.e. unbiased) estimate my population statistic for each category of my population ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just compute the mean for each sub-category, stratified sampling is not required at all.

In order to evaluate the standard errors, you may assume homoscedasticity and hence compute one unique linear model using the categories as covariate, or avoid that assumption and treat the sub-samples as separate samples and indipendently compute the mean and the st. error in each.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm wondering, what if my sample does not capture observations from a category ? In that case, can I safely assume the mean of that category same as the mean of my entire sample ? Also, is there a rule of thumb or a formula which would tell me if the number of observations from a particular category in my sample are good enough for estimating the population statistic for that category ?

Comment: @Harsh in general you cannot assume the mean of unseen categories is the same as the one of your general sample, however, that value is probably your best guess. It depends and it is a too complex subject to address in a comment, maybe post another question.

Comment: @Harsh I don't know any rule of thumb for that, I'd suggest you to compute the st. errors and see if they are small enough for you. The bigger the sample, the smaller the errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help!